# How to color overlapping hours on amCharts?

Tags: amcharts

I need to be able to mark overlapping hours on Gantt chart, so suppose i have the following data - the chart should be rendered like in the picture - so where the red rectangles are - there should be a different color to represent it...[image]

```
{
name: "Donald",
fromDate: "2018-01-01 13:00",
toDate: "2018-01-01 15:00",
color: colorSet.getIndex(1).brighten(0)
},
{
name: "Donald",
fromDate: "2018-01-01 14:00",
toDate: "2018-01-01 17:00",
color: colorSet.getIndex(2).brighten(0)
},
{
name: "Donald",
fromDate: "2018-01-01 16:00",
toDate: "2018-01-01 24:00",
color: colorSet.getIndex(8).brighten(0)
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/roy_barak/pen/LYgOWPb)

Comment: One way to go is to use transparency for colors [codepen fork](https://codepen.io/kikon-do/pen/OJBOgaz?editors=0010)